# android studio will remove view id which is needed when using data binding

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

For example

```
<layout>
 ...
 <LinearLayout>
   <TextView 
         ...
     android:id="@+id/textView">
 </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The activity like this

```
...
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
  binding.textView.setText("textView");
}
...
```

When I select **Refactor-Remove Unused Resources**.

Then checked **Delete unused @id declarations too**.

Android Studio will delete the id in the layout.

How to prevent this problem.

Comment: It looks like a bug! File it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug

Comment: I have reported the issue. @George Mount